# Best way to store user information for my iOS app

Tags: ios, database, store

What kind of database do you suggest? I want to store user email, username, password, and a couple other random pieces of information. It doesn't have to be fancy. Just a simple database. Are there any free options?

Comment: Why are you storing a password? Look at using the keychain if so.

Comment: ok, but what if i want to store user created content. for example if i ask them to pick a number between 1 and 10. and i want to always remember that number between login sessions. i will need to store the number in a database right?

Comment: You can store that anywhere. Your question was about user information which should be secure.

Comment: define anywhere by giving me an example please. do you mean in a database? my question is about storing email, username, password, and a couple other random pieces of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user information needs to be stored in the keychain to keep it secure.

Any other information could be stored in any one of:

1. User defaults `NSUserDefaults`
2. File on disk (maybe a plist)
3. Database `Core Data` (technically just a file on disk)

Which you choose depends on what the data is, how much there is and what kind of access you need to it.

If your data is small and chosen by the user as some kind of setting then user defaults makes sense and is the lowest cost for you to implement.

To use a database, check out [`Core Data intro`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

Comment: thanks very much, great answer. i will need a database though i think, because i want other users to be able to see each other's information. i should have made that clearer in my question.

Answer (score 3):

Store it in a plist.  If you're talking about data pertaining to one or a few users, that's probably the easy thing.  [here](http://iosdevhelper.blogspot.com/2011/04/plists.html) is a simple example.

Comment: thanks for answer. i think i will actually need a database so user's can see certain information about each other's answers to questions. any suggestions on best documented and supported databases for ios dev?

Answer (score 3):

Wain is right but I think as you want to store small amount of data for further use, the most efficient ways is to use `NSUserDefault`.

`NSUserDefault` stores data in `NSDictionary` type things.

I think this is the step you have to take:

1- check if data exists. I mean if user selected the number if the last run of your app. So in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
NSMutableDictionary *userDefaultDataDictionary =  [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:ALL_DATA_KEY] mutableCopy];

if (userDefaultDataDictionary) {
   // so the dictionary exists, which means user has entered the number in previous app run
   // and you can read it from the NSDictionaty:
   if(userDefaultDataDictionary[LABLE_KEY]){
        //and store it
    }
}
```

2 - you can implement some method like `syncronize` to store data in `NSUserDefault` every time something has been changed.

```
- (void) synchronize
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryForUserDefault = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:ALL_DATA_KEY] mutableCopy];
    if(!dictionaryForUserDefault)
        dictionaryForUserDefault = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    dictionaryForUserDefault[LABLE_KEY] = //data you want to store

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dictionaryForUserDefault forKey:ALL_DATA_KEY];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

P.S. and don't forget to `#define` your keys for your dictionary:

```
#define LABLE_KEY @"Lables"
#define ALL_DATA_KEY @"AllData"
```

Comment: thank you. but won't i need a database if i want users to be able to see each other's information. like if user a wants to know what user b put for something, that will have to be stored in a database right?

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't get your question here completely. Users A and B use same device or different devices? I mean if you want to store data in one and only one device, `NSUserDefault` can be used. Or for example if you want users to interact over Internet or something like that? Can you provide more information about your question?

Comment: users a and b are on different devices.

Comment: and how do you want them to interact each other?

Comment: just for a simple example: imagine a simple app where people log in and they pick a number from 1-10. i want to be able to store what each user picks so that any user can look at the statistics for each number picked. an example for this app would be that a user could click "show statistics" after they select their number, and they could see how many people chose each number.

Comment: oh, I think you need a central database, a website for example that stores the data in it and your app should be able to connect to the server and request the current number for the current user and other information like total number of some specific number.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say database, store in Sqlite. There's some provided stuff for it already in xcode.

The entire database is contained in one file, which can be moved around if you need to.

Here is some more [information](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-making-our-app) on how to use one in your app.

Comment: thank you this is the type of answer i was seeking. i should have been clearer in my question. i was really wanting to know if there was a common or well supported/documented way of storing information for users in a database like this.